# Detecting whether a file is currently being read

Tags: c, file-io

I'm writing something utilizing the libonion library, which is multithreaded, and was just wondering how you would go about detecting whether any file pointers declared are currently being *read* by any other threads or not.

(Basically I want to create manually-handled temp files where they're removed if no one's reading from them anymore.)

Comment: you could just remove the tempfile after opening, after the last process has closed them they will automatically be removed from the filesystem.

Comment: Do what hochl said. There is no reason to wait to remove temp files. A good implementation of the stdio `tmpfile` function should remove the file before it even returns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File pointers are just a pointer to a file resource and whether some other thread is reading it cannot be determined by just looking at the pointer. You may want to declare a mutex and a global lock-count alongside the file-pointer. When ever any thread is intending to read it, it can obtain a shared lock on the mutex increase the lock-count and release it after decrementing the lock-count when the thread has no intention to further read the file.

You can query this lock-count to see if the value is zero, in which case you can safely release it.

Also note, as this lock-count is global and you can end up in a race condition, reading and updating the lock-count variable should be done exclusively.

Comment: POSIX provides a `rwlock` primitive for this purpose. No sense reinventing the wheel... Also, if OP is really using `FILE *` and not low-level file descriptor access, it's almost surely impossible to do anything meaningful where multiple threads are reading the same `FILE` at once, so the (single) reading thread could just call `flockfile` for the duration of its usage, then `funlockfile` when it's done. The thread that wants to reap temp files could then use `ftrylockfile` to test of the file is still in use. But still, I think it's better to do like in the comments and avoid the whole issue.